# python sql escape forward slash not working

Tags: python, mysql, sql, insert, escaping

I am trying to execute an sql statement that should add some data to a database like so:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Actors (imdbPageId, fullName) VALUES (%s, %s)" % ( db.escape_string(self.imdbID), self.name))
```

I have also tried:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Actors (imdbPageId, fullName) VALUES (%s, %s)" % ( self.imdbID, self.name))
```

But i keep getting this error regardless of using the `escape_string` or not. See below:

> MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/name/nm0991810,  Mahershala Ali)' at line 1")

I am pretty sure it has to do with the forward slash but i cant get it to work. How do i fix this issue?

If any more information is needed let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
query = "INSERT INTO Actors (imdbPageId, fullName) VALUES (%s, %s)"

cursor.execute(query, (self.imdbID, self.name))
```

If I am not mistaken `mysqldb` takes care of this for you.

Otherwise you can do:

```
cursor.execute(query, (db.escape_string(self.imdbID), self.name))
```

Comment: so after trying your first suggestion i dont have the error anymore YAY! but my table is still empty :( any suggestions why this could be happening? or should i ask a new question for this?

Comment: are you committing your query? I don’t know if it’s in autocommit mode or not

Comment: what exactly does that mean? i am new to sql and python

Comment: means actually committing your results to the database. after you run that try doing cursor.execute(‘commit;’) and see what happens

Comment: just figured it out, it was `connection.commit()` but thanks! your first remark made me see the light :P!